# Library not found when compiling

Tags: c

I'm encountering an issue when trying to compile a C project. 
My folder contains one .c, one .h, my library directory and a few text files.

When manually compiling with my own main.c (`gcc get_next_line.c main.c Libft/libft.a`), everyone works fine.
I use a script to pass the unit-tests though, which gives me this type of error when I launch it (the functions appearing are the ones in my library which are used in my .c).

When running the same script on a friend's computer, compilation works fine.
I didn't put everything here (there's tons of code in the Makefile I use for this script), but if anyone needs some precisions I'll be glad to try and provide them.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iv75W.jpg

EDIT: I'll copy all the text what I got when trying to get the compilation:

```
make gnl
find: /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/includes: No such file or directory
find: /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/srcs: No such file or directory
make exec_tests
find: /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/includes: No such file or directory
find: /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/srcs: No such file or  directory
echo "tests/01_test_simple.spec.c 
      tests/02_test_eof_with_close.spec.c 
      tests/03_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/04_test_return_values.spec.c   
      tests/05_test_error_handling.spec.c 
      tests/06_test_line_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/07_test_two_lines_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/08_test_few_lines_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/09_test_line_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/10_test_two_lines_of_16.spec.c  
      tests/11_test_few_lines_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/12_test_line_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/13_test_two_lines_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/14_test_few_lines_of_4.spec.c
      tests/15_test_line_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/16_test_line_of_8_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/17_test_line_of_16_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/30_bonus_multiple_fd.spec.c 
      tests/40_hard_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/41_hard_test_large_file.spec.c 
      tests/42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line.spec.c"
      tests/01_test_simple.spec.c 
      tests/02_test_eof_with_close.spec.c 
      tests/03_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/04_test_return_values.spec.c 
      tests/05_test_error_handling.spec.c 
      tests/06_test_line_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/07_test_two_lines_of_08.spec.c  
      tests/08_test_few_lines_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/09_test_line_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/10_test_two_lines_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/11_test_few_lines_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/12_test_line_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/13_test_two_lines_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/14_test_few_lines_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/15_test_line_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/16_test_line_of_8_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/17_test_line_of_16_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/30_bonus_multiple_fd.spec.c 
      tests/40_hard_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/41_hard_test_large_file.spec.c 
      tests/42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line.spec.c
make re -k -C /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/libft
Object files deleted.
Library deleted.
Compilation finished.
make -k -C ../testframework/v3/
rm -f *.o
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ggdb -I includes -c srcs/**/*.c
ar rc libmt_framework.a *.o
gcc -g -I . -I ../testframework/v3//includes 
      -I /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL 
      -I /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/includes 
      -I /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/includes/builtin 
      -I /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/libs/libtowel/includes -D__MOULITEST__ -DPROTOTYPES=
      "MT_ADD_PROTO(01_test_simple); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(02_test_eof_with_close); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(03_test_medium_string); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(04_test_return_values); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(05_test_error_handling); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(06_test_line_of_08); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(07_test_two_lines_of_08); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(08_test_few_lines_of_08); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(09_test_line_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(10_test_two_lines_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(11_test_few_lines_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(12_test_line_of_4); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(13_test_two_lines_of_4); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(14_test_few_lines_of_4); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(15_test_line_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(16_test_line_of_8_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(17_test_line_of_16_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(30_bonus_multiple_fd); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(40_hard_test_medium_string); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(41_hard_test_large_file); 
      MT_ADD_PROTO(42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line); "
      -DADD_TESTS=
      "MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 01_test_simple, suite_01_test_simple); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 02_test_eof_with_close, suite_02_test_eof_with_close); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 03_test_medium_string, suite_03_test_medium_string); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 04_test_return_values, suite_04_test_return_values); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 05_test_error_handling, suite_05_test_error_handling);
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 06_test_line_of_08, suite_06_test_line_of_08); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 07_test_two_lines_of_08, suite_07_test_two_lines_of_08);
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 08_test_few_lines_of_08, suite_08_test_few_lines_of_08); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 09_test_line_of_16, suite_09_test_line_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 10_test_two_lines_of_16, suite_10_test_two_lines_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 11_test_few_lines_of_16, suite_11_test_few_lines_of_16); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 12_test_line_of_4, suite_12_test_line_of_4);
       MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 13_test_two_lines_of_4, suite_13_test_two_lines_of_4); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 14_test_few_lines_of_4, suite_14_test_few_lines_of_4);
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 15_test_line_without_nl, suite_15_test_line_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 16_test_line_of_8_without_nl, suite_16_test_line_of_8_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 17_test_line_of_16_without_nl, suite_17_test_line_of_16_without_nl); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 30_bonus_multiple_fd, suite_30_bonus_multiple_fd); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 40_hard_test_medium_string, suite_40_hard_test_medium_string); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 41_hard_test_large_file, suite_41_hard_test_large_file); 
      MT_ADD_SUITE(mt, 42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line, suite_42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line); 
      " -DRENDU_PATH="\"/nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL\"
      " tests/01_test_simple.spec.c 
      tests/02_test_eof_with_close.spec.c 
      tests/03_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/04_test_return_values.spec.c 
      tests/05_test_error_handling.spec.c 
      tests/06_test_line_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/07_test_two_lines_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/08_test_few_lines_of_08.spec.c 
      tests/09_test_line_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/10_test_two_lines_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/11_test_few_lines_of_16.spec.c 
      tests/12_test_line_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/13_test_two_lines_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/14_test_few_lines_of_4.spec.c 
      tests/15_test_line_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/16_test_line_of_8_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/17_test_line_of_16_without_nl.spec.c 
      tests/30_bonus_multiple_fd.spec.c 
      tests/40_hard_test_medium_string.spec.c 
      tests/41_hard_test_large_file.spec.c 
      tests/42_hard_test_one_big_fat_line.spec.c 
      main.c utils.c /nfs/zfs-student-2/users/acottier/Taf/GNL/get_next_line.c  -o get_next_line_tests -L../testframework/v3/ -lmt_framework
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_ft_strclr", referenced from:
        _get_next_line in get_next_line-b43645.o
  "_ft_strdupchr", referenced from:
       _ft_traitement in get_next_line-b43645.o
       _ft_nettoyage in get_next_line-b43645.o
  "_ft_strjoin", referenced from:
       _ft_traitement in get_next_line-b43645.o
  "_ft_strlen", referenced from:
       _ft_traitement in get_next_line-b43645.o
  "_ft_strlenchr", referenced from:
       _ft_traitement in get_next_line-b43645.o
       _ft_nettoyage in get_next_line-b43645.o
  "_ft_strnew", referenced from:
       _get_next_line in get_next_line-b43645.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make[2]: *** [exec_tests] Error 1
make[1]: *** [all] Error 2
make: *** [get_next_line] Error 2
```

(I made some editing, the output in the shell juste isn't readable)

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Any error messages you want us to consider go *in the question itself*, not in an external service.  And text form is far preferred to images.  Copy&paste is your friend.

Comment: Post the error here, not in a picture. When the picture goes down eventually, your question becomes useless for everyone.

Comment: Maybe u need to add some `-lxxx` options to link with a dynamic library required by your program.

Comment: Do not post links to outside sources of images of code & error messages.  Just post your code & errors here, in the question.

Comment: Please also show the whole compiler invocation, not just the error

Comment: To me the errors don't seem to indicate that the library is not found. I can not see it in the gcc invocation at all (you had it in the manual command line which worked). The linker just complains about symbols it cannot resolve, which would be consistent with that (not instructed to link against it). Of course I may be missing something. Another possibility is a mismatch between header version and binary library version (compiling works, but the definitions are not in the library); but such errors usually don't concern so many functions.

Answer (score 0):

these two lines are the main problems:

```
gcc -Wall -Werror -Wextra -ggdb -I includes -c srcs/**/*.c
ar rc libmt_framework.a *.o
```

Suggest:

```
SRCS := $(WILDCARD srcs/*.c)
OBJS := $(SRCS.o:.c)

CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -Werror -ggdb 

NAME := libmt_framework.a

.PHONY: all
all: $(NAME)

*.o: *.c
<tab>gcc $(CFLAGS)  $< -o $@ -I./includes

$(NAME): $(OBJS)
<tab>ar -rcs $@ $^
```

any libraries should be referenced when creating the executable.

with something like:

```
$(EXECNAME): $(NEW_OBJS)
<tab>gcc -static -o $@ $^ $(LFLAGS) -LpathtoLibrary -lshortlibraryName
```